# How to delete elements of a circular list until there is only one element left using python?

Tags: python, list, circular-list

How would I go about iterating through a list from 1-100, where I delete every other element starting with the first element, and repeat that step until there in only one element left in the list. Would I have to use a circular linked list, or can it be done just using loops and conditional statements?

Comment: As an aside, does anyone have any insight into the math behind this? i.e. a formula for the index you should get with a list of length `n`. There's a connection, I'm sure of it. With `n = 100` you get `63`. With `n = 1000` you get `511`. With `n = 10000` you get `8191`.

Comment: @JesseMu, `math.pow(2, math.floor(math.log(n, 2))) - 1`

Comment: @gnibbler really interesting. Have an explanation?

Comment: @JesseMu, take the highest power of 2 that's less than `n` and subtract `1`. Apparently we misunderstood the "circular list" though. See the comments on my answer.

Comment: OP can you explain the "circular list"?

Comment: Are you sure the answer for n=100 isn't 71?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume the circular list structure, when the last element of the list is deleted, the next element to be deleted is not the first one in the remaining list any more but the second one. Thus,

```
L = range(100)
st1=len(L)%2
st2=0
while len(L)>1:
    del L[st2::2]
    st2=(st1+st2)%2
    st1=len(L)%2
    print L
```

should be correct.

The result is

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 81, 83, 85, 87, 89, 91, 93, 95, 97, 99]
[3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31, 35, 39, 43, 47, 51, 55, 59, 63, 67, 71, 75, 79, 83, 87, 91, 95, 99]
[7, 15, 23, 31, 39, 47, 55, 63, 71, 79, 87, 95]
[7, 23, 39, 55, 71, 87]
[7, 39, 71]
[7, 71] 
[71]
```

Answer (score 4):

This deletes every other element over and over until just one is left

```
>>> L = range(100)       # for Python3, use L = list(range(100))
>>> while len(L) > 1:
...     del L[::2]
... 
>>> L
[63]
```

I'm not sure what the "circular list" means, but maybe this modification is needed

```
>>> L = range(100)
>>> while len(L) > 1:
...     del L[len(L)%2::2]
... 
>>> L
[99]
```

The `len(L)%2` means to `del L[1::2]` if the length of L is odd

Or if you like to see what's going on:

```
>>> L = range(100)
>>> while len(L) > 1:
...     del L[len(L)%2::2]
...     L
... 
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 81, 83, 85, 87, 89, 91, 93, 95, 97, 99]
[3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31, 35, 39, 43, 47, 51, 55, 59, 63, 67, 71, 75, 79, 83, 87, 91, 95, 99]
[3, 11, 19, 27, 35, 43, 51, 59, 67, 75, 83, 91, 99]
[3, 19, 35, 51, 67, 83, 99]
[3, 35, 67, 99]
[35, 99]
[99]
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the list has odd number of elements because of "circular list" constraint.

Comment: @ysakamoto, noone else here seems to understand the "circular list" constraint either. Can you elaborate what it means for us?

Comment: For example, 2nd list to 3rd list is not correct.
In 2nd list, the last element deleted is 99. Because of "circular list" structure, the next number to be deleted is the not first element of the remaining list. Thus, 7 is not deleted in the 3rd list.

Comment: @ysakamoto, is the second version in my answer ok?

Comment: Posted my version of answer.

Comment: By circular list I meant if the last number to be deleted from the list is in the last position of the list then the next number to be deleted would not be the second number in the most current list. So @ysakamoto had the right idea.

Answer (score 3):

How about using Python's handy [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) syntax:

```
while len(best_list_ever) > 1:
    best_list_ever = best_list_ever[1::2]
```

The expression `best_list_ever[1::2]` is a list of every other element in the original list.

Edit: I'm actually pretty confused about the circular constraint thing, but if it's accurately documented by ysakamoto then maybe look to gnibbler's answer.

Answer (score 2):

This answer simply keeps appending the items you wish to keep

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> L = range(100)
>>> for i in islice(L, 1, None, 2):
...     L.append(i)
... 
>>> i
71
```

equivalently without using islice

```
>>> L = range(100)
>>> i = 1
>>> while i < len(L):
...     L.append(L[i])
...     i += 2
... 
>>> L[-1]
71
```

memory efficient version using deque

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> L = deque(range(100))
>>> while len(L) > 1:
...     _ = L.popleft()
...     L.append(L.popleft())
... 
>>> L
deque([71])
```

These all give a value of 71, which doesn't agree with @ysakamoto's answer

Comment: You are right. I fixed an error in my answer...

Answer (score 1):

long code:

```
num=int(input())
num_list=[]
for j in range(num):
    num_list.append(j+1)
k=0   
while len(num_list)>1:
    new_num_list=[]
    l=0
    while k+2*l<len(num_list):
        new_num_list.append(num_list[k+2*l])
        l=l+1
    if (k+2*l)%(len(num_list)-1)==1:
        k=0
    else:
        k=1
    num_list=new_num_list[:]
    print(num_list)
print(num_list[0])
```

short code:

```
num=int(input())
l=num-2**(len(bin(num)[2:])-1)
print (2*l+1)
```

reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with two nested while loops

```
pseudo code

    // if there is more than one element, lets keep working 
    while(list.size > 1) {
      // Know there is one element, thus safe to assume 0
      int i = 0;

      // retrieve list size, going to be mutating list 
      int l = list.size

      // iterate through list  
      while(i < l) {
        // delete element, we want to delete the next element but skip previous, thus floor / 2
        list.delete(floor(i / 2));

        // skip every other element, thus increment by 2
        i = i + 2;
      }
    }
```

Same can be done with for loops or any iterative loop.  Should you print elements while doing this, you should see elements deleted in order of (assume list size of 10)

Loop 1
0,2,4,6,8

Loop 2
1,5,9

Loop 3
3

Leaving you with element 7 from original list

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although not as compact as the other answers, here is my version.  I'm new to Python and learning a lot by looking at others' answers.

```
mylist = range(20)
print mylist
while len(mylist) > 1:
    for i in range(len(mylist) / 2):
        del mylist[i] 

    print  mylist
```

The result:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
[3, 7, 11, 15, 19]
[7, 15, 19]
[15, 19]
[19]
```